# How to store api response to core data swift

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, offline

I am trying to make offline caching in core data. I have 7 categories in my program (photo is below) and for each of them I added id's in my model. I want to save specific response that contains articles.
What I have done for now:

- Created entity an News added there attributes that I have to save.
- Made a model of my core data
- created a func saveUserData (here I want to include core data model, but I think I did it wrong)

The problem is, I don't know how to save an object, the whole response that would store a different data for each category? Can anybody help me to accomplish that plz?

Here is my code:

```
 class CategoryDBModel: NSManagedObject { @NSManaged var articeModel: [ArticleDBModel]

func saveUserData(art: ArticleDBModel ) {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

let newArticle = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "News", into: context) as NSManagedObject
newArticle.setValue(art.imageUrl, forKey: "imageUrl")
newArticle.setValue(art.idButton, forKey: "idButton")
newArticle.setValue(art.linkUrl, forKey: "linkUrl")
newArticle.setValue(art.sourceName, forKey: "sourceName")
newArticle.setValue(art.titleName, forKey: "titleName")

do {
    try context.save()
    print("Success")
} catch {
    print("Error saving: \(error)")
}
```

}

```
class ArticleDBModel: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var linkUrl: String?
    @NSManaged public var imageUrl: String?
    @NSManaged public var titleName: String?
    @NSManaged public var sourceName: String?
    @NSManaged public var idButton: String?
}
```

//var articles: Articles?

//api call, and core data fetching

Basically, I trying to Predicate category's ID in my fetchData.
[image]

//Category's **id**

[image]

//core data model

[image]

[image]

//news entity

[image]

Comment: Post code as text and not as images

Comment: It’s not clear what your issue is, “I don’t know how to save” doesn’t tell us much.

Comment: It's valid to consider to use a URLCache for offline capabilities. While this can also be challenge to get right (and requires planning the "freshness" of the data with the backend team and "DataProviders" which are usually "Publishers"), I would say, it's less a challenge than using CoreData functioning as a Cache - AND to get everything right, too.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the issue is that I am facing a problem on saving response to func saveUserData () and therefore I added details(images).

Comment: But what is the issue, the images aren’t telling us that?

Comment: Issue: in Api call, I can't convert response into core data. I added photos in order to make it more clear, but ... don't know why are u asking so far